# Git update local ignoring few files (is not .gitignore)

Tags: git, git-pull, git-reset, git-fetch

```
Scenario:
 Bitbucket:
  file1 
  file2 
  file3  

 Local:
  file1 - person1 is working on it
  file2 - person2 is working on it
  file3 - common with personal hardcoded configuration
  untracked files
```

person1 commits and pushes his changes on file1.
How person2 can update file1 in his local without resetting file2, file3 and untracked files?
It's a while that I'm trying to do it but I still don't find an easy way!
Thanks.

Comment: When you push a new change onto server, only push the file1 instead of whole bunch of files. 

How are you pushing the files to git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untracked files won't be updated when you fetch new commits from the remote repository. As for `file2` and `file3` (which I'm assuming *are* tracked), you'll want to set the `skip-worktree` flag on those. That way Git won't update them in your working directory.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

> **--[no-]skip-worktree**
>   When one of these flags is specified, the object name recorded for the
>   paths are not updated.

More [specifically](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit):

> When reading an entry, if it is marked as skip-worktree, then Git
>   pretends its working directory version is up to date and read the
>   index version instead.

You can set the `skip-worktree` flag on a specific file with the [`git-update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) command:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree path/to/file2
```

If you later want to unset the flag, use the `--no-skip-worktree` option instead:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree path/to/file2
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this useful command to list all the skipped files "git ls-files -v . | grep ^S".

Comment: Another thing, what do you use after that? fetch and reset?

Comment: Stupid question, maybe it's "personal". I mean to update you local in your usual workflow.

Comment: No problem :) You can update your local repository with [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).